# Does a MySQL index on columns (A,B,C) optimize for queries than just select/order by (A,B) only?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Given a table with columns A,B,D,E,F.
I have two queries:

- one that orders by A then B.
- one that orders by A, then B, then C

I want to add an index on (A,B,C) to speed up the second query.
I'm thinking this will also speed up the first query.  Is that correct?  Or should I add a second index on (A,B)?

Or am I oversimplifying the problem of performance-tuning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an index on all three of them. You don't need a second index.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks!